# R: Exponent returning infinity

Tags: r, exponential, infinity, exponentiation, natural-logarithm

I need to remove logarithms of my data and thus am taking e to the power of the values which are logarithmed.

My issue is that when I have e to the power of more than 709 R returns the value of infinity. How can I surpass this?

> e^710 
>   [1] Inf

Thanks :)

Comment: I don't think you want to do this. You'd need arbitrary precision numbers. But there is probably a better alternative, e.g., typically you'd try to work with the logs.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to work with numbers that big you can use a `Rmpfr` package.

```
library('Rmpfr')

x <- mpfr(710, precBits = 106)
exp(x)

1 'mpfr' number of precision  106   bits 
[1] 2.233994766161711031253644458116e308
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try!However before I took the logarithms, Rstudio had no problem showing me these big numbers. I wouldnt mind if the numbers would be rounded, but I need to get the original numbers, which are in trillions.

Comment: @John_Doe And why do you need to take an exponent if you have original numbers?

Comment: @John_Doe You could also try package [Brobdingnag](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Brobdingnag/index.html).

Comment: I have original numbers of only some of the variables, most of the variables are based on the original, but it would  quite time consuming to transform the original numbers to include all the necessary parameters.

Comment: A natural logarithm of numbers in the trillions would never be near 710, so in which range were the numbers you originally had, before you took their logarithms? FWIW, *ln(9,999,999,999,999,999) = 29.933...*, i.e. not even close to 710.