# Is there a way to handle calculations invovling exponential of big values in R?

Tags: r, precision, numeric

I have looked a bit online and in the site but I did not find any solution. My problem is relatively simple so if you could point me to a possible solution, much appreciated.

```
test_vec <- c(2,8,709,600)
mean(exp(test_vec))

test_vec_bis <- c(2,8,710,600)
mean(exp(test_vec_bis))
exp(709)
exp(710)
# The numerical limit of R is at exp(709)
```

How can I calculate the mean of my vector and deal with the Inf values knowing that R could probably handle the mean value but not all values in the numerator of the mean calculation ?

Comment: Have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45436913/r-exponent-returning-infinity

Answer (score 1):

There is an edge case where you can solve your problem by simply restating your problem mathematically, but that would require that the length of your vector is extremely large and/or that your large exp. numbers are close to the numeric limit:

Since the mean `sum(x)/n` can be written as `sum(x/n)` and since `exp(x)/exp(y) = exp(x-y)`, you can calculate `sum(exp(x-log(n)))`, which gives you a relief of log(n).

```
mean(exp(test_vec))
[1] 2.054602e+307
sum(exp(test_vec - log(length(test_vec))))
[1] 2.054602e+307

sum(exp(test_vec_bis - log(length(test_vec_bis))))
[1] 5.584987e+307
```

While this works for your example, most likely this won't work for your real vector. 
In this case, you will have to consult packages like `Rmpfr` as suggested by @fra.

Comment: Good idea but would only work for values close to the limit as you said. Thanks ! The 'Rmpfr' package is the best solution I found till now.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way where you qualify to only select those in your `test_vec` that give an answer < `Inf`:

```
mean(exp(test_vec)[which(exp(test_vec) < Inf)])

[1] 1.257673e+260

t2 <- c(2,8,600)
mean(exp(t2))

[1] 1.257673e+260
```

This assumes you were looking to *exclude* values that result in `Inf`, of course.

Comment: Thanks for the response. No, I actually considered this option but I do have to include every value. Truncation is not an option in this case...